# how to copy multiple line from text file C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to copy multiple lines from text file(cisco config file): based on the below condition 
 if the line starts with interface copy from interface until  '! '

my file is like :

> !
>
> access-list 1>
>
> !
>
> interface 1
>
> ip address xx.xx.xx.xx
>
> !
>
> interface 2
>
> ip address xx.xx.xx.xx
>
> !
>
> route 1
>
> !

I try the below  code :

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\My File2.txt");
foreach (var line1 in lines){
  string firstWord = line1.Split(' ').First();
  if ((firstWord == "access-list") && (!line1.Contains("remark ")))
  {
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "\r\n" + line1;
  }
  else if (firstWord == "nat")
  {
     TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + "\r\n" + line1;
  }
     else if (firstWord == "interface")
  {
     var result = lines.Substring(line1.LastIndexOf('!') + 1);
     TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text + "\r\n" + result;
  }
```

but I get only one line as output

Comment: in case if the line start by interface i get only                                    interface 1                                                                                                      but i need                                                                                          interface 1                                                                                                    ip address xx.xx.xx.xx

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to keep your algorithm, this will work for you.

```
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\My File2.txt");

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<lines.Length;i++)
        {
            var line1 = lines[i];
            if (line1 == "!" || line1 == " ") continue;

            if (line1.StartsWith("access-list")) && (!line1.Contains("remark ")))
            {

                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + "\r\n" + line1;
            }
            else if (line1.StartsWith("nat"))
            {
                 TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text + "\r\n" + line1;

            }
            if (line1.StartsWith("interface"))
            {
                var str = line1;
                while (!Equals(lines[i + 1], "!"))
                {
                    str += lines[i + 1];
                    i++;
                }
                TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text + "\r\n" + str;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use "File.ReadAllText" instead of "File.ReadAllLines". "File.ReadAllText" returns a string with the complete text file text. After that, you can use the "String.Split" method to generate a string array.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllText("C:\\My File2.txt");
var seperatedStrings = lines.Split('!');
```

Each index of "seperatedStrings" contains what you want.

UPDATE: Here is a code snippet, that can help:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllText("C:\\My File2.txt");
        var seperatedStrings = lines.Split('!');

        foreach (var oneString in seperatedStrings)
        {
            if (oneString.Contains("access-list"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Access-List: " + oneString);
            }else if (oneString.Contains("nat"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nat: " + oneString);
            }else  if (oneString.Contains("interface"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Interface: " + oneString);
            }
        }
```

This is the output of my code snippet:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the file structure shown by you `interface` and `ip address` are on different lines. So you won't get it in same iteration of for loop. When you find that `firstWord == "interface"` you will need to set a flag that will tell you that next line is `ip address` and in next iteration check if that flag is `true` parse the current line as `ip address` and process it the way you want.